# How to make a div act as an infinite background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to resolve a certain issue where I want the background to always be the same color.

The initial view looks great, but if the user zooms out with the browser then they see a blank white area on the bottom which indicates that the content has ended. (Note that the width of the content always populates the free space by growing as they zoom out)

I have a div that wraps my content and it is supposed to display the background color that I want. Is there a special way to always make the div container cover the height area like it does the width area?

I don't want to modify the body tag since my web app is not built to allow that.

Things I tried:

- Applying the style to the body tag. It worked, but it would apply
  this to all of my pages since this stylesheet is shared.
- Set the height of the container to 100% which did nothing.

Code I am using:

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <section class="color-1">
        <nav class="cl-effect-14">
            <a href="#/intro" class="animsition-link menu-link">Start New Game</a><br/>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">Resume Game</a><br/>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link">Join Existing Game</a><br/>
            <a href="#" class="menu-link" onclick="self.close()">Quit</a><br/>
        </nav>
    </section>

</div>
```

CSS

```
   .container {
       background-color: #000;
   }

   .menu-link {
       font-family: Old Standard TT;
   }
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to include the corresponding code

Comment: Please post code you tried, what happens, and what you want to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the div's `height` and `width` properties to `100%` or `100vh` and the `position` property `absolute` or `fixed`?

Comment: That 100vh did it! Thanks Tim :)

Comment: Great to hear! Anytime :)